# Appending chrome history to popup html and it keep flickering

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to append chrome history URL, lastVisitTime, and Sno, everything work fine when URL is print as static text.

Problem arises when I print url's in table, it keep appending url, i don't understand this behaviour.

Here is popup.js

```
var count = 0;
var table = url = "";
var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
chrome.history.search({text: '', maxResults: 2}, function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(page) {
        count++;  
        url = page.url;     
        table += '<tr class="table-warning"><td scope="row">'+count+'</td><td>'+ url +'</td><td>'+page.lastVisitTime+'</td></tr>'; 
        console.log('url', url);                    
    });

    tbody.innerHTML += table;
});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>History tracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">        
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Sno</th>
                    <th scope="col">Website</th>
                    <th scope="col">Time</th>                    
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody">                 
                </tbody>
              </table>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div> 
 <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try moving `tbody.innerHTML += table;` to outside of the foreach function.

Comment: Never use `+=` on innerHTML that's in a live (visible) document. Use tbody.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', yourhtml)

Comment: [How is insertAdjacentHTML so much faster than innerHTML?](//stackoverflow.com/a/7590831), also [Appending HTML string to the DOM](//stackoverflow.com/a/7327125)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking and wasting much time with it, I have found it was an CSS issue,
The container class was creating the problem so I removed the container class. It was width issue, the width of popup was not enough to show urls, so I removed time column and provide fixed width to URL column.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>History tracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
      table{
        overflow-x: scroll;
      }
      td#history_url {
        max-width: 500px;
        word-break: break-word;
        min-width: 500px;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="">     
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-hover responsive">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Sno</th>
                    <th scope="col">Website</th>                    
                    <th scope="col">Delete</th>                 
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody">                 
                </tbody>
              </table>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div> 
 <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```